# What is the difference between "ifconfig interface down" and "rfkill block"?

Tags: ifconfig, rfkill

I know `rfkill block all` will disable everything. But what about `ifconfig interfaceX down`? When I use it, it just drops the connection. And when I type `ifconfig interfaceX up` it reconnects to my old connection.

So does `ifconfig interfaceX down` disable the wireless too?

Answer (score 3):

ifconfig is used to configure your network interface. You can use it for many things such as Changing your machine's IP address.

> Ifconfig is used to configure the kernel-resident network interfaces. 
>   It is used at boot time to set up interfaces as necessary. After that,
>   it is usually only needed when debugging or when system tuning is
>   needed.  Mark an interface "down".  When an interface is marked
>   "down", the system will not attempt to transmit messages through that
>   interface.  If possible, the interface will be reset to disable
>   reception as well.<sup>1</sup>
>
> rfkill is a small tool to query the state of the rfkill switches,
>   buttons and subsystem interfaces.  It is a command-line tool with
>   which you can query and change RFKill-enabled devices on the system.
>   To obtain the tool, install the rfkill package.<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[manpagez](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ifconfig/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[Red hat](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/RFKill.html)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

rfkill can softblock the connection or inform you that it is disabled by a hardware switch.  This makes it more informative than ifconfig or iwconfig.